# How to call another fragment from one fragment on hitting back button?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a **MainActivity** in my application, from where all the fragments are called using Navigation Drawer. And default fragment of the activity is 'A'. So everytime i open the application, 'A' fragment is called. when I hit 'back' from another fragment B, I want to get to default fragment 'A', as what happens in gmail - from any fragment if we hit back, it returns to default fragment "Primary mails".

I tried calling the 'A' fragment by adding the following code to the **onPause()** of fragment 'B'.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    fragment = new A();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragTransaction.replace(R.id.a,fragment ).commit();

}
```

But when I hit back, fragment 'A' is called for a moment, but then the application closes unexpectedly.

**Logcat :**

> 01-14 12:44:42.264: E/WindowManager(4655): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.litchi.iguardian.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41da6348 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-513,243} that was originally added here

Whats the correct way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the behavior when you press the back button, because by default it will destroy launched activity and you see your fragment while callbacks goes from `onPause()` until `onStop()` and activity is not visible for you anymore. Just override this method, it must solve the problem:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But yeah, it is for global control, for switching fragments you may also call `addToBackStack();` when you want return previous fragment by pressing back button.

Answer (score 0):

to back to previous fragment see below code :

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(...);
```

put this in onBack event

to call popBackStack method you first need to call addToBackStack method while calling fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new CurrentClass();
detail.setArguments(bundle);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.content_frame, detail).addToBackStack("back")
.commit();
```

Comment: I tried this code in the onPause() method. It doesn't work. It closes the application unexpectedly with the same logcat as above.

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing that code in onPause() you can write that code in onBackPressed() of your main activity .